# Zoom out version of webpage on mobile device

Tags: php, android, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to make my website to have a zoom out version of normal desktop scale to smaller scale on any mobile device. The reason I did this because my webpages has huge iframe containing adobe flash. The iframe itself is already 900px wide.

What I tried to put the code below in my header but it doesn't work.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.25"/>
```

Anyone has the idea how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting viewport's width equal to your webpage's width. It should be something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=900" />
```